# how to get parent tids of a taxonomy term

Tags: 8, taxonomy-terms

I used this code to get the parent ids , but the result is a huge object .  how do I get the parent id's and term names from the resulting object ?

```
 $ancestors = \Drupal::service('entity_type.manager')->getStorage("taxonomy_term")->loadAllParents($tid);
```

Answer (score 33, accepted):

In $ancestors you'll find an array of the parent terms starting with the term $tid itself:

```
$ancestors = \Drupal::service('entity_type.manager')->getStorage("taxonomy_term")->loadAllParents($tid);
$list = [];
foreach ($ancestors as $term) {
  $list[$term->id()] = $term->label();
}
```

Comment: Does the field_fieldname go where it says $tid? example = loadAllParents($field_myvocab); Do I need to create a variable?

Comment: If you start with a node: `$field_myvocab = $node->field_myvocab; $tid = $field_myvocab->target_id`. If you have multiple terms stored in the field  you can use the field variable as an array and loop over it.

Comment: what happens for the first level of taxonomy terms (the ones which does not have parent)?